# adding ansible_python_interpreter to task with expect module fails to get command with become_user

Tags: ansible, python3, expect

I'm writing a task for `CentOS7` inventory in which have to go through prompt dialogues, which I think is best candidate for andible's `expect` module.

```
- name: setup some command
  become: yes
  become_user: user1
  expect:
    command: some_command
    responses:
      'Do you want to continue? [yes/no]': 'y'
```

Above task required `pexpect` package on inventory, and version available is `2.3`
as shown in below error, whereeas expected version: >=3.3

```
fatal: [target1]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {"discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"}, "changed": false, "msg": "Insufficient version of pexpect installed (2.3), this module requires pexpect>=3.3. Error was 'module' object has no attribute '_run'"}
```

As a workaround I installed `python3` and it's `pexpect` module on inventory, and specified `ansible_python_interpreter` in the task to resolve it.
this time it was unable to locate the command for the `become_user`

```
- name: setup some command
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
  become: yes
  become_user: user1
  expect:
    command: some_command
    responses:
      'Do you want to continue? [yes/no]': 'y'
```

Below is the error for the task

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: pexpect.exceptions.ExceptionPexpect: The command was not found or was not executable: some_command.
fatal: [target1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "The command was not found or was not executable: some_command."}
```

please suggest what's missing

Comment: `some_command` is not valid. Did you forget to change that?

Comment: @Panki actually some_command is a command which is is found in user1's $PATH. I can run it from shell with user1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on a Debian system but could get it working by using the full path of the command. You can get the full path of a command using `which`, for example `which some_command`, on the remote server.

An example of your Ansible playbook task using the full path

```
- name: setup some command
  become: yes
  become_user: user1
  expect:
    command: /usr/bin/some_command
    responses:
      'Do you want to continue? [yes/no]': 'y'
```

With some more research I learned that this is due to Ansible doing a batch login

> In any case this is due to Ansible doing a batch login, which does not source the same files as a live login, this depends on your system's configuration and can be changed by setting the PATH the same way for both types of logins.
> [source](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/56044)

You can try this out yourself with `ansible <host> -m shell -a "echo $PATH"` or in an Ansible playbook

```
- name: check modinfo
  shell: |
    echo $PATH

# "stdout": "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games",
```